# does ubuntu 12.10 run on acer aspire one d270 with intel Atom N2600 processor

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

Can I upgrade my ubuntu 12.04 to version 12.10 on an acer aspire d270? It came with an Intel Atom N2600 CPU. Much thx in advance!

Comment: If 12.04 works 12.10 will work too... they basically are the same at the moment (both get updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only people who can say for certain are the people who have one.

You are in a position of power though: you could download the LiveCD/USB and boot to it. Yeah, it's 700MB and the time to burn to USB but it's the safest way to find out if your hardware is still supported; it'll give you a realistic idea of how well a new install or upgrade should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Take a live CD of any recent Linux OS and just try to run it from that live cd. You will get a good idea of how will it work after installation.

**EDIT:**

Yes, thanks for that. Use USB image writer to write an iso image to your USB then plug it in as usual

Comment: Or use a USB stick, since that machine doesn't have an optical drive.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia atom cpu guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom). it will run 32bit, and MAY tun 64 bit. There were issues with the 64bit implementation so some,but not all motherboards support it.

Comment: Thanx to all for the quick replies. Really appreciate it. I'll stick with my 12.04 version for now, and maybe later do the live install from USB. Provided I find the time. Though I must say that it does sound awkward that I brand new laptop should be outdated in terms of hardware regarding the support of ubuntu 12.10. I just bought the acer netbook recently, and it came with a rudimentary linux OS. One should expect that its hardware supports any linux OS. Anyhow, thanx again! :)